# module 'word2vec-google-news-300' has no attribute 'load_data'

Tags: python-3.x, gensim

I tried to use `gensim.downloader` to download `word2vec-google-news-300`, but my network isn't very reliable, so I downloaded `word2vec-google-news-300.gz` and `__init__.py` from github and put them into `~/gensim-data/word2vec-google-news-300/`.

But when I use `api.load("word2vec-google-news-300")` to load this model, I received error like this:

> AttributeError: module 'word2vec-google-news-300' has no attribute 'load_data'

My code:

```py
import gensim.downloader as api
model = api.load("word2vec-google-news-300")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
Extract GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin from word2vec-google-news-300.gz

```
from gensim.models import KeyedVectors
from gensim.test.utils import datapath
wv_from_bin = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(datapath(r"path to GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin"), binary=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue on Ubuntu, I checked the access rights for .gz file in this directory and elevated the access rights for all users.

`cd ~/gensim-data/<anyvectors-package>
ls -al
sudo chmod u+rwx <anyvectors-package.gz>`

Now, try loading vectors again.
It worked for me.

[Refer related GitHub issue thread and answer here](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim-data/issues/37#issuecomment-599605309)